# Find the largest possible number of squares 1x1

Tags: analysis, word-problem

Martin is playing 210 pieces of 1x1 small squares. What's the largest possible number of squares, all with different side lengths, that he could from using some of the 210 pieces of 1x1 small square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can have this, with n=210:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor} {n \choose i^2}=\sum_{i=1}^{14} {210 \choose i^2}=7.96806628515312 \cdot 10^{61}
$$

The largest term is for $i=10$, ${210 \choose 100}=7.13939343164154\cdot 10^{61}$, which is the closest term for the maximum combinatorial ${210 \choose 105}$.

Comment: This problem is in grade 8. We might not need the Sigma sign. And the answer is 8 but the book doesn't show the solution. Thank for answering , your answer is correct:)

Comment: But can u prove it by using another way!?